# Use html-webpack-plugin to inject bundle script tags into <asp:Content> tag in legacy .aspx files with master page?

Tags: asp.net, webpack, webforms, webpack-4, html-webpack-plugin

I'm fairly familiar with webpack and the html-webpack-plugin and have used them on a couple of other (SPA) projects. But in this new project I have to convert a legacy multi-page website to use webpack. There is a custom asp.net handler (ashx) that currently bundles (and minifies in prod builds) registered scripts by placing a comma separate list of script names on the query string of the .ashx reference in a script tag: `<script src="Script.ashx?i=jquery,jquery-ui,...">`.

One of the problems is that almost all the pages use a master page. So, there is no `<body>` tag to use for the html-webpack-plugin.

If I was dealing with a small number of entries I would have no problem using a few html-webpack-plugin templates to inject the scripts and place the output files in the correct place in the project folder structure. But there are 50 aspx pages in various locations in the project folder structure. So I would very much like to avoid maintaining separate templates for all of those pages.

**But given that there no `<body>` tags in any of these files, how do I inject the scripts into the desired place?**

I've built a custom code generator to read all the aspx pages in the project and find the Script.ashx references. It then parses the comma separated query string and generates a companion .js file with one import statement for each of the referenced scripts. These companion .js files will be what are referenced in the webpack "entry" array. So, for instance /home.aspx gets a companion /home-entry.js file. That file is in the webpack config: `entry { "home" : "./home-entry", ... }`. And the corresponding Script.ashx is commented out in the source aspx page. I'm also code generating the webpack `entry` array and the html-webpack-plugin references for each `entry` into the `plugins` array in the webpack config.

Home.aspx (snippet):

```
<asp:Content ID="Content6" ContentPlaceHolderID="footerPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Script.ashx?i=jquery,jquery-migrate,jquery-ui,jquery-watermark,popr,acrobat-detection,pdflinkfix,device,navbar,jqdialoghelper,home&v=<%= "" + MyNameSpace.Scripts.ScriptHelpers.AssemblyVersion %>"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

Entry example:

```
"home" : "./home-entry",
```

Plugins example:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin( {
    chunks: ['home-entry'],
    alwaysWriteToDisk: true,
    filename: "./home.aspx",
    inject: 'body', // or what?
    chunkSortMode: "dependency",
    hash: true
} ),
```

home-entry.js:

```
import '/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min'
import '/Scripts/jquery-migrate-min'
import '/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min'
import '/Scripts/jquery.watermark.min'
import '/Scripts/popr/popr'
import '/Scripts/acrobat_detection'
import '/Scripts/PDFLinkFix'
import '/Scripts/Device'
import '/Scripts/NavBar'
import '/Scripts/jqDialogHelper'
import '/Scripts/Home'
```

Expected result: The big problem is that I cannot figure out if there is a way to tell html-webpack-plugin to inject into a specific tag. I.e. what I want it to do is find  the specific `<asp:Content ID="Content6" ContentPlaceHolderID="footerPlaceHolder" runat="server">` tag and inject the script tags into it. Note that there are other `<asp:Content>` tags that have different `ContentPlaceHolderID` values. So html-webpack-plugin has to find the one with `ContentPlaceHolderID="footerPlaceHolder"`.

Actual result: I believe with a default html-webpack-plugin options, in the absence of a `<body>` tag, the plugin will place the scripts at the end of the file. Which will confuse asp.net.

Comment: I don't know about webpack. But you are making 2 false assumptions about the aspx pages. 1: An `<asp:Content` tag does not render client side, so you cannot reference it. 2: There will always be a `body` tag, the one from the Master Page. The Master and one or more content pages will be merged into a single html page.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the way master pages interact with aspx pages. And the script tags need to go into the asp:Content tag so the are rendered in the final html stream. Remember that webpack is *mostly* a pre-runtime build tool. So the bundles are compiled prior to publication to the site. That's why the aspx pages need the script references at design time.

Comment: Well, I think I've come up with a plan. I will just use an SSI in the <asp:Content> tag and have my webpack templates render just the script tags into the included file: like `<!-- #include file="~/home-scripts.html" -->`. Testing this now.

Comment: I was going to post this as an answer to my own question, but I still have not answered my actual question. I have come up with a working solution. What I ended up doing was setting up a single empty template in the project. And for every entry page there is now a set of files in the project. So for `/SomeFolder/SomePage.aspx` I am code generating `/SomeFolder/SomePage-entry.js`. `html-webpack-plugin` is writing `/SomeFolder/SomePage-bundles.inc` with just the script tags. Inside that aspx file I am replacing the old `Script.ashx` reference with: `<!-- #include file="SomePage-bundles.inc" -->`

Comment: Well, I hit a snag with the above setup. In my POC I decided to try to incorporate my css. And now the include files are being written with a `<head>` tag that encloses the `<link>` tags for my styles. So I would still like an answer to my original post.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the codebase I am working on has a similar setup to yours. I searched for a solution for quite a while to no avail. I ended up writing my own webpack plugin which handles this situation for me now. It defaults to writing to an index.aspx page but you can specify whatever type of page and/or location you'd like it to write to.
You can check it out here. Feel free to install and use if you'd like. Its not super polished or anything but its working well for our setup.
https://github.com/pckessel/MPAInjectionWebpackPlugin